# Javax.swing.JOptionPane can't print out PrintStream variable

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I don't know how to print out a string and a variable in the joptionpane. is it possible? If not then what should i do?

```
String peopleadded = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many people do you     want to add");
    int peopleadded1 = Integer.parseInt(peopleadded);
    String[][] People = new String[peopleadded1][2];
    System.out.println("put your name in the array");
    People[0][0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Put your Name");
    System.out.println("put your password in the array");
    People[0][1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Put your Password");
    PrintStream person = System.out.printf("Your array num [%s] and name is %s and your password is %s", 0, People[0][0], People[0][1]);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, person);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"Text"+varName+"moretext"` etc. (Without printstream, directly in the optionpane)

EDIT:
You can use this:

```
int peopleCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many people do you want to add?", "Add People", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
String[][] addPeople = new String[peopleCount][2];
for (int i=0; i<peopleCount; i++) {
    addPeople[i][0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Person "+(i+1)+"\'s name:","Person "+(i+1),JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    addPeople[i][1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Person "+(i+1)+"\'s password:","Person "+(i+1),JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
String people="";
for (int i=0; i<peopleCount; i++)
    people+="Person "+(i+1)+":\n     Name: "+addPeople[i][0]+"\n     Password: "+addPeople[i][1]+"\n";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,people,"People added",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Or, if you want to display each person in seperate dialogs:

```
int peopleCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many people do you want to add?", "Add People", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
String[][] addPeople = new String[peopleCount][2];
for (int i=0; i<peopleCount; i++) {
    addPeople[i][0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Person "+(i+1)+"\'s name:","Person "+(i+1),JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    addPeople[i][1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Person "+(i+1)+"\'s password:","Person "+(i+1),JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
for (int i=0; i<peopleCount; i++)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Person "+(i+1)+":\n  Name: "+addPeople[i][0]+"\n  Password: "+addPeople[i][1],"Person "+(i+1),JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Sorry i don't follow. it prints out printstreamblahblah for the JOptionpane. it prints out in the field, print.io.printstream

Comment: <code>JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your array num ["+num+"] and name is "+People[num][0]+" and your password is "+People[num][1])</code> where num is an integer indicating the person's number in the array (0 in your code)

Comment: I think you can't use a printstream here, but you can use it to write to the console for example (System.out.println or System.out.printf)

Comment: ok. I will try that. if it does not work, should i use a different utility. i know it works for array lists that are already made, but not for one's you have not yet created.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: if you make an array

   ' int [] array = [3];
    array[1] = 1;
   array[2] = 2; '
it and try to print that onto the joptionpane, it will print out. but it wont print out the array that i have. it seems it only prints out arrays that iare already made.

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: im trying to make an array where i ask the person how mahy people he wants to add, ask his name and password for each person, and prints out all the people he added on the screen. i have that down already in printing that out on the console, but i want to do all that in a joptionpane.showmessagedialog screen.

Comment: Ok. it worked, thank you so much. i never thought of it that way.